# python while statement with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to iterate through a dictionary and get user response.

At the second to last question, I want to specifically declare that there is one more question left.

I am having trouble combining a while statement with for loop. This is my code:

```
# my dictionary

q_dict = {"where are we? " : "usa",
          "who are you? " : "jon",
          "how old are you? " : 22}

# my function 

def q_prompt(question, answer):

    response = input(question)

    if response != answer:

        print("incorrect")

    else:

        print("correct!")


# having trouble here with this logic combining for loop and while     

run = 1

for key, val in q_dict.items():
    
    q_prompt(key, val)
    

    while run < (len(q_dict)-1):
        print("on to the next question")
        run += 1

    else:
        print("on to the last question")  # i would like this to print when there is one more question left  

    print("no more questions")
```

after the user responds to "who are you", I want the program to say "on to the last question". then when the program is done (after user answers the last question", it says "no more questions". I am having trouble iterating through each question and increasing the value of 'run'. Running this code does not get the desired result.

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run this code? What do you want it to do? Please [edit] your question to include more details and to ask a specific question for something you are stuck on.

Comment: In your own words, what is the purpose of a `while` loop? Where the code says `print("on to the next question")` and then `run += 1`, how many times should that happen *before anything else happens*? In your own words, where the code says `else:`, what do you expect that to line up with, and how do you intend for it to work? In what situation would you expect that code to run? (Hint: while this is not a syntax error, it's not very common. What is the *usual* thing paired with `else`?)

Comment: "Running this code does not get the desired result." It is not helpful to tell us this. Instead, please explain: what result *do* you get? *How is that result different* from the result you want? *What specific things did you try* in order to [understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and [diagnose](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the problem? After doing those things, what is your understanding of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd want to use a while loop here. Why not just have an if-statement like so:

```
q_dict = {"where are we? " : "usa",
          "who are you? " : "jon",
          "how old are you? " : 22}

for key, val in q_dict.items():
    
    q_prompt(key, val)
    

    if key != list(q_dict.keys())[-2]:
        print("on to the next question")

    else:
        print("on to the last question")  # i would like this to print when there is one more question left  

print("no more questions")
```

Note, I've also un-indented your final print statement since otherwise it will execute on every iteration.

Comment: I was trying to have a solution that could could be applied to a much larger dictionary with many different questions, not just this simple dictionary. So I want that when the user answers the second to last question, the program says "on to the last question". I hope that is more specific.

Comment: See updated answer. Still no need for a while loop. You can simply check against the second-to-last key in your dictionary. @E50M

Comment: I was hung up on needing to use a while loop - this solves it quite nicely

Comment: @E50M, it's best not to use while loops unnecessarily and they also come with significant performance drawbacks due to how they're implemented in Python.